# Invalid request missing grant type

Tags: android, kotlin, oauth-2.0, jwt

I'm doing a post call to my OAUTH2 authentication with Android, trying to recibe my Bearer Token.

I'm using Kotlin language and i'm doing the post request with Volley.

The problem is that when i do my post request with Postman, it work's perfect, but when i do it in the same way using Volley post, my API REST yells: Invalid Request Exception, missing grant type.

And my android yells: Unexpected response code 400 for http://192.168.1.254:8081/oauth/token

Android call:

```
private fun loginUser() {

        var grant_type = "password"
        var username = etUsername.text.toString()
        var password = etPassword.text.toString()

        val credentials = "angularapp"+":"+"12345"

        // Post parameters
        // Form fields and values
        val params = HashMap<String,String>()
        params["grant_type"] = grant_type
        params["username"] = username
        params["password"] = password

        val jsonObject = JSONObject(params)


        val request = CustomJsonObjectRequestBasicAuth(Request.Method.POST, Network.API_URL_LOGIN,jsonObject,
            Response.Listener{ response->
                Log.d("RESPONSEEEE", response.toString())
                try {
                    // Parse the json object here
                   Log.d("Response" ,response.toString())
                    val intent = Intent(this, PatientsActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra(Tags.FLOOR.toString(), ((spiFloor?.selectedItemId!!+1)))
                    startActivity(intent)
                }catch (e:Exception){
                    e.printStackTrace()

                }
            }, Response.ErrorListener{
                Log.d("ERROR", "VOLLEY ERROR")
            },credentials
        )

        // Add the volley request to request queue
        VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request)

    }

    // Class to make a volley json object request with basic authentication
    class CustomJsonObjectRequestBasicAuth(
        method:Int, url: String,
        jsonObject: JSONObject?,
        listener: Response.Listener<JSONObject>,
        errorListener: Response.ErrorListener,
        credentials:String
    )
        : JsonObjectRequest(method,url, jsonObject, listener, errorListener) {

        private var mCredentials:String = credentials

        @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
        override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
            val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
            headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            val auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(mCredentials.toByteArray(), Base64.NO_WRAP)
            headers["Authorization"] = auth
            System.out.println(headers.toString())
            return headers
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have an HTTP log of the Volley request? I mean HTTP reqest headers and body sent to the token endpoint - `POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1 ...`?

Comment: which version of volley in gradle are you using?

Comment: Thanks you guys, i did it in a simplest way. It was not necessary to create the custom object. It was enough adding method getHeaders and getParams. The problem was that my body haven't got this method:  override fun getBodyContentType(): String {
                    return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
                }